# Git: In pre-push hook, ignore commits which are already on any branch on the remote

Tags: git, version-control, githooks

I have a pre-push hook (which very closely resembles the example pre-push commit which comes with git) which checks for a specific string in commit messages and doesn't push if it's found.

If I make a new branch (let's say I branch off of master, and call it feature), make a few commits (not containing the string I want to avoid pushing) and try to push this to a remote, it will fail if some commit in ancient history of this branch contains that string.

How can I have git only consider commits which are not in any remote branch? Is there a way to do it without checking the reachability of each commit against each remote branch?

One way which might work is to step back from the tip of the branch being pushed one commit at a time and check if there is a remote branch pointing to it, and as soon as one is found, truncate the range being considered here. Am I along the right lines, or is there a better way?

Below is the hook.

```
#!/bin/sh

# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>

remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

IFS=' '
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
        # Handle delete
        exit 0
    else
        if [ "$remote_sha" = $z40 ]
        then
            # New branch, examine all commits
            range="$local_sha"
        else
            # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
            range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"
        fi

        # Check for bad commit message
        commit=`git rev-list -n 1 --grep '\bbad string\b' "$range"`
        if [ -n "$commit" ]
        then
            echo "Found commit with bad string in $local_ref, not pushing"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list all commits on $branch not in any $remote branch:

```
git fetch $remote
git rev-list $branch $(    # or git log --oneline
        git for-each-ref --format='  ^%(refname)  ' refs/remotes/$remote
)
```

though you can do without the `git fetch` for this purpose. So where you set `range` substitute

```
range="$local_sha $(
        git for-each-ref --format='^%(refname)' refs/remotes/$remote
)"
```

and don't quote it in command lines -- the shell will split the words apart nicely and each formatted ref will be excluded from the search.

One thing: there's an `IFS=' '` up at the top there.  Changing the shell's inter-field separators is a special-purpose kind of thing, very rarely necessary.  That one will cause it to think tabs and newlines aren't field separators, not what you want when subbing in command output.

#### Working version of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local sha1> <remote ref> <remote sha1>

remote="$1"
url="$2"

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
    if [ "$local_sha" = $z40 ]
    then
        # Handle delete
        exit 0
    else
        if [ "$remote_sha" = $z40 ]
        then
            # New branch, examine all commits not on any remote branch
            range="$local_sha $(
                    git for-each-ref --format='^%(refname)' refs/remotes/$remote
            )"
        else
            # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
            range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"
        fi

        # Check for bad commit message
        commit=`git rev-list -n 1 --grep '\bbad string\b' $range`
        if [ -n "$commit" ]
        then
            echo "Found commit with bad string in $local_ref, not pushing"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: This gives a `fatal: bad revision '^refs/remotes/origin/HEAD [newline]
^refs/remotes/origin/master'` -- it's complaining about the newline. I'm having success if I pipe the output of for-each-ref to `tr '\n' ' '`, but I wonder if there's a better way? I also need to remove the quotes around $range from the `commit=` line of the script, otherwise the negated list of refs is treated as a single ref, which it can't find.

Comment: I should have checked the quoting farther on, sorry about that. I think all you need is to correct the quoting in the `rev-list` args, i.e. sub `commit=\`git rev-list -n 1 --grep '\bbad string\b' $range\`` in tfor its original so the shell does the word splitting for you.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Do you have a better solution to the `tr` I ended up using?

Comment: Just yank it.  When I run that rev-list with `git rev-list [etc] $range`, where range was set with a c&p of the command given for it above I get correct results.  (i.e. the only two changes you make to your script are what you set `range` to and strip the quotes around it when setting `commit`)

Comment: Not for me. Maybe I should point out that in your answer you suggest the wrong line to replace -- we should not be replacing `range="$remote_sha..$local_sha"` (that line is for an update to an existing branch) but `range="$local_sha"`, which is when it is a new branch. With the script like this http://sprunge.us/CLZH I get `fatal: bad revision '^refs/remotes/origin/HEAD <newline> ^refs/remotes/origin/master'`. git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)

Comment: Um, I didn't notice your `IFS=' '` in there. Take it out.  There's no reason to cripple the shell's wordsplitting like that.

Comment: Ah. Nor did I! It's from git's built-in pre-push hook example. If you roll all this into your answer I'll accept it, or I can edit it and then accept if you prefer?

Comment: Yow. That's a bug for sure. Stuff like this once it's certainly right I'd be happy for correction-by-edit, not sure that's a good bet in general tho.  Thanks for sticking with it.

Answer (score -1):

First off, you can create a list of commits with only the commit number and the commit message:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
```

This command will give you output that looks like this:

```
ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949 changed the version number
085bb3bcb608e1e8451d4b2432f8ecbe6306e7e7 removed unnecessary test
a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6 first commit
```

(This sample output was copied from http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

You can get the last 12 of these commits as follows (substitute 12 for the number of commits you want):

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline -12
```

You can also filter for the commit numbers you want, which don't have the string:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline -12 | grep -v "the unwanted string" | awk '{print "git cherry-pick "$1;} > cherrypick.sh
```

($ grep -v filters for lines that don't contain the next parameter.  The awk command prints the first token.)

Then you can create a new branch as follows:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch_name
```

You'll be on the new branch.  On the new branch, you can reset back to the commit before the first one you're deleting (let's call this commit a11bef):

```
$ git reset --hard a11bef
```

And then you can cherry-pick the commits you want:

```
$ chmod u+x cherrypick.sh
$ ./cherrypick.sh
```

Voila!  A branch with only the commits you want.

CAVEAT: You may run into a merge conflict by doing this.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. This doesn't answer it at all. I don't want to change the branch I'm pushing at all.

Comment: It's not a big deal to create a new branch.  Whatever branch you're on, you can also push to any branch-- $git push <repo> <branch_you're_pushing_to>

Comment: But the committed branch should still have the "bad" commits in its history, since it should still linearly descend from remote/master. I don't want to remove any commits.